# Can a sound be played from a plsql block withing oracle form? I tried the below but noting is happening

Tags: plsql, oracleforms

The below code is inside when new item instance of 'BLOCK3.B' sound item.

READ_SOUND_FILE('F:\SOUND\TEST.WAV','WAVE',':B LOCK3.B'); 
PLAY_SOUND(':BLOCK3.B');

and from within a procedure defined inside oracle form I am performing the below activity.
go_item('BLOCK3.B');

Its not playing the sound.

When I am performing the below activity its playing the sound.
Using go_item('BLOCK3.B') from when new form instance.

Can anyone advise what is going wrong here.

Comment: I've never used `play_sound` before but some googling indicates that you need to do the `go_item` *before* you call `play_sound`.

Comment: Also, I suspect this only works in older versions of Forms.